# Swift - Data Model

Tags: ios, swift, model

I'm new to Swift and I find myself in the situation where I have a view controller that should manage 36 textfields and 15 labels (update with some math performed from the textfield).

Now my issue is that seems too much to connect all those outlets in the view controller.
I wanted to create a data model which will store into an Array the data and then perform the math and update the UI.

Like I said, I'm new to Swift and it seems I'm not able to create a model using outlets.

This is what I've done:

All the textfields and labels are contained in a subview inside the main view. So I've associated the subview with the class of the model (EnergyModel) which it already gives me an error right away.

Here's the code of my model:

```
class EnergyCalcModel {
    @IBOutlet weak var lightstextfield1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lightstextfield2: UITextField!

    private var _lights1: String
    private var _lights2: String

    var lights2: Double {
        if lightstextfield2.text != nil {
            _lights2 = (lightstextfield2.text!).doubleValue
        }
        return _lights2
    }

    var _lights1: String {

        if lightstextfield1.text != nil {
            _lights1 = (lightstextfield1.text!).doubleValue
        }
        return _lights1
    }

    init(lights1: Double, lights2: Double) {
        self._lights1 = lights1
        self._lights2 = lights2
    }
}
```

and in my main VC:

```
var energyModel: EnergyCalcModel!

func calculate() {
    label.text = energyModel.lights1 * energyModel.lights2
}
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: You should put all your outlets in the ViewController, and create the model using the data in the outlets.

Comment: @chengsam Adding all those outlets to the viewController will not cause performance problems? Wouldn't I Overload the viewController?

Comment: *"... it already gives me an error right away."* If you have some kind of error message, you should **always** include the text of that message.

Comment: Sorry... i cannot reproduce it anymore.... i think it was related to the class i've assigned to the view...the problem i think is that i've assigned the Outlets to the model... probably i should assign them in the controller... what scares me is the high number of the... i'm scared to overload it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're concerned about "overloading". If it's memory you're concerned about, that memory is already used when you put all these UI elements on the screen. Keeping references to them in your view controller won't make things any worse. It might make the code ugly and repetitive, for example if you end up with instance variables named `textField1` through `textField36` instead of something descriptive.

If it makes sense for your app and for the purpose of this view, go ahead and include them all. There's nothing to "overload" in that regard.

Some things that might improve the code-- depending very heavily on how you use these text fields and labels-- might include:

- Using a dynamic structure like a table view. If each table view cell has one label and one text field, you can have as many as you need easily. You can also have the number change depending on your data, if that makes sense for your needs.
- Instead of using 36 different outlets, use an outlet collection (`@IBOutletCollection`) that contains all of them. Finding the right outlet in the array may require a little work, though, because you can't rely on the array order. You might do that using the `tag` property on the view, or you might sort it somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. I'm going to implement this http://prntscr.com/fx9xk1. basically the "kWh/giorno" will update once the first two fields are insert by user. Some thing for line 18, 25 and 26 they will update with a sum once all required fields will be entered. I'm not sure if i can do it with a table view (not sure how to add all the columns if they are on different cell) but if it won't cause any memory issue, i think i might be going with normal Outlets.